# Position of VscrollBar In a TextBox Multiline

Tags: c#, textbox, scrollbar

[C#]My question is how i choose a position of scroll bar in a multiline textbox?
or if cant do this, how i do to the  VscrollBar interact with a multiline textbox?

Comment: Set the SelectionStart position in the TextBox and the call the ScrollToCaret() method.